# undefined errored: Cannot read property 'op' of undefined

Tags: solidity, remix

I am getting this error on contract deployment

> "undefined errored: Cannot read property 'op' of undefined "

when using remix and have no clue why, when I remove the `helloAddress` and remove the param it does not show

```
pragma solidity 0.4.17;

contract HelloWorld{

    address public owner;
    address public helloAddress;

    function HelloWorld (address _helloAddress) public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        helloAddress = _helloAddress;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an [issue in remix](https://github.com/ethereum/remix/issues/594) but the contract seems to run well despite the message.